# On closedness of $C^\ast$ subalgebras

Tags: definition, c-star-algebras

By definition of a $C^\ast$ subalgebra it is a closed subalgebra.

Why does it need to be closed?

This is a restriction that is not required in the case of a Banach subalgebra. (although I can't think of an example of an open Banach subalgebra example off the top of my head)

Comment: What's your definition of a "Banach subalgebra"? Usually the very word "Banach" is used to mean "closed".

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you so much for your comment. I believe this question is due to the same missing connection as my comment to your answer in the other question. Perhaps one could answer my question as follows? "The subalgebras are all closed and the reason is because we want the quotient by them to be again a Banach space".

Comment: I think it is simpler than that. Both "C$^*$-algebra" and "Banach algebra" definitions require closedness. If a subalgebra would not be closed, it would not be C$^*$ nor Banach.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You are right. What got me confused about this was that many theorems explicitly say "closed subalgebra" (like e.g. theorem 1.2.8. on page 11 in Murphy's $C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory).

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be closed because it needs to be complete.  Completeness is part of the definition of a Banach algebra.

(Incidentally, notice that a set that is not closed need not be open. If a linear subspace of a normed space is open, then it must be the whole space.)